# WPF input direction right to left

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

how can i create a masked input box with input direction right to left without manipulate the FlowDirection. Just like on the cash desk.
For example, i have a mask "00.00". When i type 1, control should show "00.01" and when i type 100 it will be "01.00".

Or, somebody knows an existing toolkit with such control? I didn't found.

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might rewrite `TextBox`  `Template`, with your needs. you can retrive standard `Template` and play with them, it must works.